# How to POST an object using RestKit-0.2?

Tags: ios, restkit-0.20

Most of the tutorials out there are for REST-0.1, and I'm having trouble getting to POSTing objects like NSDictionnary *dict = @{"name": "Joe", "age" : "12"}

Quick steps would really be helpful like :

1-create RKObjectManger

2-create RKRequestDescriptor

...

Also, a lot of tutorials talk about RKObjectMapping; but why are they needed for POST? isn't the user just posting data, why would he expect anything in response?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to post a dictionary without actually mapping the values and you don't expect / care about the response then you should use `AFNetworking` directly (which RestKit is built on top of). RestKit is useful for POSTing updates and receiving confirmations of the new object.